# can NULL be turned for jintArray datat type?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am new to java. I am writting a jni layer in android, in which i have to return jintArray.

```
static jintArray nativeMyFunction (jint param1,  jint param1 );
```

Some cases in this function implementation, i need to return NULL. Is it a valid case if i return NULL ?

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't return a basic type (like `int`, `double`, etc...) you can always return `null`.

The question is: Does the caller of your method `nativeMyFunction(...)` handle the `null` case properly? Does he know that he has to handle the `null` case? If yes, then `null` can be a totally valid return value!

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Yes, the user knows we return null. For valid cases, i return array of integers. But the first comment i did not understand.   "if you don't return a basic type (like int, double, etc...) you can always return null"?

Comment: If the return type of your method is a basic data type (like int) then you cannot return null. For example: `public int getSomeInteger() {...}` can not return `null`, because a basic data type cannot be converted to `null`.